# SMTP relay anti-relaying and LIMIT/QUOTA

Tags: proxy, smtp

I need some help to face this problem.
I have 2 LAN connected to the same router.

My first LAN is the office LAN and left on the internet with one public IP address.
My second LAN is the datacenter LAN and left on the internet with some public IP addresses
(because each client has its own public IP address.)

On my first LAN I have an Exchange server, it's not a problem.
But on my second LAN, I have nothing, just an SMTP relay to forward the mail to the Internet. The SMTP relay is only for the second LAN.

This SMTP relay allows filtering the domain sender and the domain receiver (anti-relaying), but doesn't allow other filters.
On this LAN, I have some web servers and they (Unix or Microsoft) send mail to partners and other clients... sometimes too much.

I need to replace this SMTP relay by another one which can filter the domain (for anti-relaying), and limit the mail traffic by server.

Examples:

- Server A can send on his own domain with a limit (or quota) of 100 mail per hour.
- Server B can send on his own domain with a limit (or quota) of 500 mail per hour.

I have no need to receive mail, just to send.
If the SMTP relay had graph/statisctis, it would be a positive factor.

Comment: what SMTP capable software your servers are running on both networks? What are the OS you are using for it?

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky : The SMTP-relay is only for the second LAN. I have Debian, CentOS, Windows 2K3, Windows 2k8. The newsletter and ads are sent via Apache or IIS.

Comment: If you can run your relay on Linux, postfix has all the options you need.

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky : I found a documentation for anti-relaying (to restrict open relay). But i cannot find anything on QUOTA/LIMIT. Is it native or is it a module ? tx for your answers

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=postfix+rate+control+anvil

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky : Thanks for your link, but i already see that and this line make me uncomfortable :       "IMPORTANT: These limits must not be used to regulate legitimate traffic: mail will suffer grotesque delays if you do so. The limits are designed to protect the smtpd(8) server against abuse by out-of-control clients. " (from : http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html)